# Stata: Wilcoxon Rank-Sum and Signed-Rank Test Results

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, nonparametric, stata

Males and females took exams from two different boards. I want to calculate if there is a difference between females who took the board 1 exam vs females who took the board 2 exam. I am using the rank-sum test but how can I get the one-sided p-value in Stata rather than the two sided one? For example, I want to test if females who took board 1 exam > board 2 exam. Secondly, I want to test differences among males and females within a specific board. I am using the signed-rank test but again, how to do one sided? Should I just halve the resulting p-value in Stata?

Comment: I would like to say various things to you, but one is that you can't spell your name correctly.

Comment: I can. That is my real name. Of-course I am not the President of Russia but my parents gave me the same name... It's unusual but not impossible.

Comment: I can't disprove that, naturally, but you are using the President's photo,  so you are playing a small game, and so am I. If you claim you look like him too....  As I understand it, he uses "Vladimir". (FWIW, I don't think using that name will be universally appreciated here.)

Comment: Can you help me with my questions please? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I would use Somers' $d$ for your problem. There is an excellent Stata implementation.

Comment: Hmm. Ok I will give it a try but what do you think about the specific question I asked regarding one-sided vs two-sided? I searched the forums and while some people asked the same question the answers weren't so clear. Do we just halve the p-value?

Comment: I wouldn't focus on the P-value at all: that is usually a waste of time and effort. The Stata implementation will give you pr(values in group 1 > values in group 2) which is directly related to your problem and that is why I recommend you change to Somers' $d$.

Comment: I totally appreciate your point but I really need to learn how to calculate the one-tailed p-value as well. I am using display "Prob < z = " normal(r(z)) "     Prob > z = " 1-normal(r(z)) but I don't think my sample size is large enough to justify this. Is there a simple way to get Stata to calculate the one-sided p-value for the tests I mention? Please let me know if there is so we can get an answer to the question and close this thread!

Comment: Sorry, but as I think you're asking the wrong question I don't have anything extra to say.